# Multiple mapping One to many in Jpa

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

If I've, in a single entity A, multiple relations (many to one) towards an entity B (annotated with one to many)? Do I've to put an annotation for each occurrence of A in B?

Example:

Entity A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient")
@TableGenerator(name = "tab_gen_pa", initialValue = 30000, allocationSize = 1)
public class Patient implements Serializable, Comparable<Patient> {

 @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "birth_region")
    private Region birthRegion;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "birth_province", length = 2)
    private Province birthProvince;

    @ManyToOne
    @Column(name = "birth_municipality")
    private Municipality birthMunicipality;

@Column(name = "living_region")
    @ManyToOne
    private Region livingRegion;

    @Column(name = "living_province", length = 2)
    @ManyToOne
    private Province livingProvince;

    @Column(name = "living_municipality")
    @ManyToOne
    private Municipality livingMunicipality;
```

Entity B: Region for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "region")
@TableGenerator(name = "tab_gen_re", initialValue = 30, allocationSize = 1)
public class Region implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "livingRegion")
    private List<Patient> patients;
```

Do I've to insert also in Region:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "birthRegion")
        private List<Patient> patientsBirthRegion;
```

??

Comment: Yes !!!..You have to if you wanna have this kind of relationships..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below pair of association mappings,

```
@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "birth_region")
private Region birthRegion;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "birthRegion")
private List<Patient> patientsBirthRegion;
```

defines the `bidirectional association` only between a list of `patient`s and their `birthRegion`. Now if you want similar type of associations between other `regions` and the `patients` in those regions, you need to have this type of association mappings among them.